# Como marcar checkbox com uma única cor?

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema:

- Ao entrar na edição do meu produto preciso que na parte onde tem as imagens dos produtos, cada produto tenha sua cor específica. Ex:
  [image: edit.blade.php]

Porém ele está marcando todas as cores de todos os produtos no mesmo checkbox, como no exemplo abaixo.
[image: edit.blade.php]

---

Página de edição está assim.

**edit.blade.php**

```
@foreach($cores as $cor)
                <div class="agrupa" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center">                        
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cor_id_produto[]" id="cor_id_produto" style="margin:10px" value="{{  $cor->id }}"
                     {{ in_array($cor->id, array_pluck($produto->produtoFotos, 'cor_id_imagem'))  ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                    <input type="color" class="form-control" disabled name="cor_id_imagem[]" value="{{$cor->hexa}}" id="cor_id_imagem[]"
                     placeholder="Hexa" style="width:100%; height:25px; padding:0; border:none;">
                </div>                                      
                @endforeach
```

**Pergunta**

- Como poderia realizar esse foreach para que ele marcasse somente a cor respectiva à sua imagem?

Desde já agradeço. Se precisarem de mais informações é só pedirem que vou adicionando aqui.

---

**FOREACH INTEIRO**

```
<div id="fotos_cores" class="fotosCores">
            <hr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">
            @foreach ($produtosFotos as $photos)
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 imgCor pull-left">
                <label for="imagens">Imagem cadastrada</label>
                <hr>
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <img src="/images/{{$photos->filename}}" class="img-responsive" width="50">
                    <input type="file" name="imagem[]" value="{{$photos->filename}}" multiple class="form-control hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 imgCor pull-right">

                <label for="cores">Cor Referente</label>
                <hr>                    
                @foreach($cores as $cor)
                <div class="agrupa" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center">                        
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cor_id_produto[]" id="cor_id_produto" style="margin:10px" value="{{  $cor->id }}"
                     {{ in_array($cor->id, array_pluck($produto->produtoFotos, 'cor_id_imagem'))  ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                    <input type="color" class="form-control" disabled name="cor_id_imagem[]" value="{{$cor->hexa}}" id="cor_id_imagem[]"
                     placeholder="Hexa" style="width:100%; height:25px; padding:0; border:none;">
                </div>                                      
                @endforeach
                <div class="removeButton pull-right"><a value="Remover" class="remDiv" style="cursor:pointer">Remover</a></div>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

---

**{{dd($produto->produtoFotos)}}**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**{{dd($cor->id)}}**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**{{dd($cores)}}**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**{{dd(array_pluck($produto->produtoFotos, 'cor_id_imagem'))}}**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Tabela produto_fotos**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90379/discussion-on-question-by-adrib-como-marcar-checkbox-com-uma-unica-cor). Caso haja interesse em prosseguir, basta clicar no link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resposta**

---

Como de costume pessoal, gosto sempre de colocar a solução que resolveu meu problema. Não sei se foi da melhor forma. O código abaixo representa a forma como consegui solucionar a pergunta *Como poderia realizar esse foreach para que ele marcasse somente a cor respectiva à sua imagem?*

---

```
<div id="fotos_cores" class="fotosCores">
            <hr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($produtosFotos); $i++)              
               <div class="form-group col-md-6 imgCor pull-left">
                <label for="imagens">Imagem cadastrada</label>
                <hr>
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <img src="/images/{{$produtosFotos[$i]['filename']}}" class="img-responsive" width="50">
                    <input type="file" name="imagem[]" value="{{$produtosFotos[$i]['filename']}}" multiple class="form-control hidden" />
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 imgCor pull-right">
            <label for="cores">Cor Referente</label>
            <hr>
            @foreach($cores as $cor)
            <div class="agrupa" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="cor_id_produto[]" id="cor_id_produto" style="margin:10px" value="{{ $cor->id }}"
                 {{ $cor->id == $produtosFotos[$i]['cor_id_imagem']  ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                <input type="color" class="form-control" disabled name="cor_id_imagem[]" value="{{$cor->hexa}}" id="cor_id_imagem[]"
                 placeholder="Hexa" style="width:100%; height:25px; padding:0; border:none;">
            </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="removeButton pull-right"><a value="Remover" class="remDiv" style="cursor:pointer">Remover</a></div>

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        @endfor
    </div>
```

---

Quero agradecer aos amigos [Francisco Melicias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/46895/francisco-melicias) e ao amigo [Bulfaitelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59502/bulfaitelo) pelas respostas que me ajudaram a entender a lógica.

**Resposta alternativa**

Enquanto criava essa resposta apareceu nosso amigo [JrD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/126116/jrd) e contribuiu também com uma resposta um pouco mais simples mas que funcionou exatamente da mesma forma que a resposta acima. Aqui vai o segundo código:

```
<div id="fotos_cores" class="fotosCores">
            <hr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">             

            @foreach ($produtosFotos as $photos)
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 imgCor pull-left">
                <label for="imagens">Imagem cadastrada</label>
                <hr>
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <img src="/images/{{$photos->filename}}" class="img-responsive" width="50">
                    <input type="file" name="imagem[]" value="{{$photos->filename}}" multiple class="form-control hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 imgCor pull-right">

                <label for="cores">Cor Referente</label>
                <hr>    
                @foreach($cores as $cor)

                <div class="agrupa" style="display:inline-block; text-align:center">                        
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cor_id_produto[]" id="cor_id_produto" style="margin:10px" value="{{  $cor->id }}"
                    {{ ($photos->cor_id_imagem == $cor->id)  ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                    <input type="color" class="form-control" disabled name="cor_id_imagem[]" value="{{$cor->hexa}}" id="cor_id_imagem[]"
                     placeholder="Hexa" style="width:100%; height:25px; padding:0; border:none;">
                </div>                                      
                @endforeach
                <div class="removeButton pull-right"><a value="Remover" class="remDiv" style="cursor:pointer">Remover</a></div>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            @endforeach

        </div>
```

> {{ ($photos->cor_id_imagem == $cor->id)  ? 'checked' : '' }}>

foi a resposta do nosso amigo. Obrigado à todos que ajudaram.